# js browser detection for IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, browser-detection

My question is the folowing

Is there a solid javascript code to detect if a browser is IE(I don't care about others)

I found [some script](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html), but it generates an undefined error in FF.

***I edited my question because I found some regex serverside solution for this on this forum
It's enough for now.***

thanks, Richard

Comment: Have you google it. This kind of thing is pretty easy to find. Maybe you can post your JS code here and we can figure out why it is not working in FF.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588940/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-browser-detection-in-javascript

Comment: @Aditya Sehgal - it's a damn fine question and even if it's easy to find on Google, it deserves it's place in stackoverflow.com

Comment: check this answer here, its THE one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7690750/104380

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find [here](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/cc-plus.html) very useful technique for IE detection using conditional tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE your favorite doc type> 
     <html> 
       <head>...</head>  
       <body>  
          <!--[if IE]>  
                  <div id="IEroot">  
          <![endif]-->  
                   <p id="IE">This browser is IE.</p>  
                   <p id="notIE">This browser is not IE.</p>  
          <!--[if IE]>  
                  </div>  
          <![endif]-->  
      </body> 
    </html>
```

You can use it and put script tag between it to define Javascript action only for IE.

Comment: Note that conditional comments are being removed from IE10+

Comment: Note the post date, two years ago. There wasn't even IE8 I guess or it was just released when.

Comment: Yeah, it's still a very useful answer, I was just pointing it out to anyone who might be using this code in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the

`navigator`

object

```
navigator.appName
```

will give the browser name and

```
navigator.appVersion
```

will give the browser version.

Another one is listed here

[Browser detect](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

Comment: thank you, that was actually thew first script I found. I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You can check browser either by using Javascript or jQuery. Javascript provides Navigator object using that you can check like:

```
function getBrowserName()
  {
    if(navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        alert("This is " + navigator.appName + " Browser");
  }
}
```

You can look example here: http://www.codegateway.com/2012/09/detect-ie-browser-javascript.html

And jQuery have Browser Object that we can use to detect browser like:

```
function getBrowser()
 {
   if ($.browser.msie) {
        alert('IE');
    }
 }
```

See example here: http://www.codegateway.com/2012/09/detect-ie-browser-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getInternetExplorerVersion()

{
  var rv = -1; 
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
  {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
  }
  return rv;
}
function checkVersion()
{
  var msg = "You're not using Internet Explorer.";
  var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion();

  if ( ver > -1 )
  {
    if ( ver >= 8.0 ) 
      msg = "You're using a recent copy of Internet Explorer."
    else
      msg = "You should upgrade your copy of Internet Explorer.";
  }
  alert( msg );
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.userAgent` can be used. The following detect if browser is IE version <= 9:

```
var browserIEInfo = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE (([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?)/);
if (browserIEInfo === null || parseInt(browserIEInfo[2]) > 9){
    // code for non IE or for IE version > 9
}

// code for IE <= 9
```