# JavaScript: The best way to detect IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, detect

Reading [this article](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/114350/#habracut) I've found a following piece of code:

```
if ('v'=='\v') { // Note: IE listens on document
    document.attachEvent('onstorage', onStorage, false);
}
```

Is this method `'v'=='\v'` a great idea? Is this the shortest way to detect IE ever?

Comment: http://ajaxian.com/archives/ievv Supposedly it's valid.

Comment: Browser detection is *never* a good idea. Note that `'v'=='\v'` is `false` in IE9+.

Comment: You're right, new versions of IE support a lot of standard-compliant features that were supported only by FF/Gecko/Opera before, so you don't need to run a fallback code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can avoid it, don't test for browsers. Do feature detection. This will mean that your code is (more likely to be) future-proof.  In this case, for instance, if you discovered that the browser was IE and decided to use `attachEvent` because of it, you would miss out on the fact that `addEventListener` (superior) is available in IE9.

In this case, test to see if `document.addEventListener` exists. If it does, you have the answer.

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener(...);
} else {
    document.attachEvent(...);
}
```

---

Edit: duri's comment above shows that this test fails in IE9 (as per standards), which actually means it is a perfect test for `addEventListener`, since that is available from IE9. *However* it is still far, far better to program for specific functionality, rather than specific browsers.

Comment: In 99.999999% of cases this is the best advice there is on the subject. But there are very rare instances when you actually may need to detect IE itself rather than particular features/functionality.

Comment: The question uses an example peripherally -- no need to critique it. Strangely, ievv is a form of feature detection (albeit not a fine grained one.)

Comment: @dvdrtrgn I don't remotely understand that.

Comment: Q: shortest ie detection ever? A: sure seems to be... (also, it "detects" the handling of vertical-tabs)

Comment: This would be great if IE 11 didn't lie about a load of features to try and make sites treat it like Firefox or chrome when it simply doesn't work well enough to be treated as a standard browser yet(and it's debatable if it ever will, since the browser has resorted to lying). ActiveXObject is falsey, the user agent has been changed, and they removed conditional comments.

Comment: i have to detect IE because it does this calculation wrong... window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('padding-left')  maybe only when both left and right padding are relative values

Answer (score 12):

You can check for Trident, IE's engine, by the following:

```
var trident = !!window.ActiveXObject;
```

As stated on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.94).aspx) it is only supported in IE.

**Edit:**

Note: above code returns false in IE-11, If you want to detect also IE-11 use this:

```
var isIE = "ActiveXObject" in window; //window.ActiveXObject !== undefined;
```

Comment: this is THE answer. i'm impressed. short and to the point. feature detection for IE10 is problematic, because it seems to be a damn fine leap forward in everything.

Comment: It is `false` in IE11

Comment: At @VitorCanova says, it's false for IE11. Don't use this way any more people

Answer (score 6):

To check if the browser is Internet Explorer, use feature detection to check for `documentMode`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc196988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This code checks to see if the browser is Internet Explorer 8, 9, 10, or 11:

```
var docMode = document.documentMode,
    hasDocumentMode = (docMode !== undefined), 
    isIE8 = (docMode === 8),
    isIE9 = (docMode === 9),
    isIE10 = (docMode === 10),
    isIE11 = (docMode === 11),
    isMsEdge = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge/") > -1;

// browser is IE
if(hasDocumentMode) {
     if(isIE11){
         // browser is IE11
     } else if(isIE10){
         // browser is IE10
     } else if(isIE9){
         // browser is IE9
     } else if(isIE8){
         // browser is IE8
     }
} else {
   // document.documentMode is deprecated in MS Edge
   if(isMsEdge){
         // browser is MS Edge
   }
}
```

Checking `document.documentMode` will only work in IE8 through IE11, since `documentMode` was added in IE8 and has been deprecated / removed in MS Edge.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406036%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

If you really need to detect IE7, check for `document.attachEvent`:

```
var isIE7 = (document.attachEvent !== undefined);
if(isIE7) {
      // browser is IE7
}
```

IE7 returns a object, but if the browser is IE11 (for example), then this would come back as `undefined`, since IE11 does not have `attachEvent`.

**UPDATE:**

Added check for MS Edge. `document.documentMode` was [deprecated in MS Edge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn384051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Due to the nature of MS Edge, you can check for `Edge/` in the User Agent. Microsoft is making it difficult to use feature detection in MS Edge.

Comment: Very useful answer. If your project does not support IE7, it's the cleanest way for IE detection. Hope it will work in IE12+, so you should not come back to your codebase and fix it again :). However, I'm leaving  "feature detection" to be the selected answer because strange other-browser-engines (especially mobile) still exist and new can appear at any moment. To say briefly, feature detection provides the best quality.

Comment: @Dan This answer should still work when IE12+ comes out due to the **documentMode** still being a property in the **document** object in IE.

Comment: @Dan This can also detect if the browser is IE8 rendering the  Document Mode in IE7. if you want to check for iE7 than you can check for **document.attachEvent**

Comment: I never trust IE, they don't worry much about compatibility
http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/
http://www.engadget.com/2013/03/25/ie-11-says-it-is-like-firefox/

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript `includes()` method is not supported in IE11 and earlier. So you can use code to check whether if the `includes()` method is supported. This can work for all versions of IE. But the includes method isn't for early versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera. This may not be the most efficient way to detect IE.

```js
var aString = "something";
if(!aString.includes){
    alert("You are using IE");
} else {
    alert("You are not using IE");
}
```