# Detecting IE8 with JavaScript using document.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, conditional-operator, browser-detection

I came across this code in a project I am working on that is used to detect if the browser is IE8:

```
var isIE8 = function(){ return (!document.addEventListener) ? true : false; };
```

I don't understand why the conditional operator `? true : false` is used to return true if true and false if false. The logical NOT `!` is applied to the value of `document.addEventListener` and will always return a Boolean value, would this not do exactly the same thing:

```
var isIE8 = function(){ return (!document.addEventListener); };
```

[.addEventListener Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Browser_compatibility)

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690676/javascript-the-best-way-to-detect-ie/20201467#7690723) was the closest information I could find on this.

Thanks for taking a look :)

Comment: I don't see a purpose for the ternary operator. It could have simply been !! instead. Maybe the original coder thought it was easier to read. I'd suggest though dropping this flag completely and coding for features, not browsers.

Comment: As a sidenote, checking for the presence of `addEventListener` is a bad way to detect IE8, inserting conditional statements would be better IMO. It is however a good way to determine if `addEventListener` is present, and if not try `attachEvent` instead, but then the name isIE8 would be somewhat misleading.

Comment: In other words, only the person who wrote that code would be able to answer in this case. All we can do is guess.

Comment: @KevinB `!!` would set the variable isIE8 to false in IE8 `!` would make more sense. As I suspected there seems to be no reason for it. Thanks for the input @adeneo I agree the variable name is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would just like to detect IE8, checking for `addEventListener` will do the job. But if you would like to check for IE and its versions in general, I find this method the most intuitive and most useful:

```
var uA = navigator.userAgent;
var browser = null;
var ieVersion = null; 

if (uA.indexOf('MSIE 6') >= 0) {
    browser = 'IE';
    ieVersion = 6;
}
if (uA.indexOf('MSIE 7') >= 0) {
    browser = 'IE';
    ieVersion = 7;
}
if (document.documentMode) { // as of IE8
    browser = 'IE';
    ieVersion = document.documentMode;
}
```

You're also catching higher IE versions in Compatibility Mode/View this way. And using the script is very easy:

```
if ((browser == 'IE') && (ieVersion <= 10)) 
    // do something, for example:
    document.documentElement.className += ' ie10-';
```

Comment: This is a nice implementation for detecting IE versions, thanks. After having re-read my question I've realised it was more about the thinking behind using conditional operators to return a boolean value from a value that is already boolean, not detecting IE. Sorry about that.