# Add different JavaScript effets to Bootstrap 3 dropdown on mobile and desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I found multiple scripts that apply a slidedown/up effect to a Bootstrap 3 dropdown, but none of them work for me when the screen is smaller (XS/Mobile).

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115833/adding-a-slide-effect-to-bootstrap-dropdown) has various options I've tried without success.

All the options I try do not function properly on mobile devices because of the `nav-collapse` below `768px` width. It seems to mix up the function with the `bs collapse` function and my dropdown mobile styles.

Ideally I would like the dropdown to trigger on  hover for desktop and on click for devices but both with a nice slide effect.

Can anyone help please!

Comment: As a rephrase: The dropdown does not work properly on mobile devices, you want it to trigger on hover on the desktop and on click on mobile. Correct?

Comment: yes correct. I have the hover and click working in most for tablet and desktop, but in mobile view ( below 768px ) it combines the slide dropdown on hover as well as keeping the collapsed nav that activates on click.

Comment: So why not check if `screen.width > 767`, then use the one solution, else the other?

Comment: to correct my previous post. I stated - "but in mobile view ( below 768px ) it combines the slide dropdown on hover.." This is incorrect as it obviously can't apply effect on hover in mobile. I meant it applies a dropdown on top of the collapsed nav if this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your response but how do I write what you are suggesting?

Comment: I am currently testing this script. `$('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
});`

Answer (score 1):

Distinguishing between mobile and desktop via `screen.width` might do the trick. In one case, use `.hover`, else `.click`.

```
if ( screen.width > 767 ) { // desktop
    $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() { 
         $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
    }, function() { 
         $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(); 
    });
} else { // mobile
    $('.navbar .dropdown').click(function() { 
         $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
    }, function() { 
         $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(); 
    });
}
```

This code could be more elegant, f.ex. by deduplicating the if-else via using `hover` and `click` as parameters.

Maybe the idea is more clear here.

Nowadays, distinguishing via features (f.ex. `screen.width`) [is superior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440296/reliable-way-to-detect-desktop-vs-mobile-browser) to distinguishing via browsers or mobile/desktop.

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts but this does not seem to solve the issue. It works fine  above 767px but still the same issue with below 767px.

Comment: @SteveJoiner: does the above `//mobile` code trigger on below 767? (use `console.log` if you can access it, else `alert`)

Answer (score 0):

To correct the effects on mobile, you could try to add this CSS and tell me if that works? This was a temporary fix on older Bootstrap.

```
.dropdown-backdrop {
    position: static;
}
```

You can also apply different styling on mobile/desktop with media queries like so (this is just an example of how to use the media queries, you can replace with what you need):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```